# Programmatically Maximize Window On Half Of Screen

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, aero

I want to maximize a random window on the left side of my screen. Can I use Windows Aero functions from my code ? This window **can** be maximized like that with the mouse. I just want to do that programmatically.

I use `C#` and I can get the `IntPtr` of the window.

*If possible without faking mouse or keyboard input.*

Comment: Unfortunately not, Microsoft in their wisdom did not provide any public API for the aero snap functionality.

Comment: This can be done without p/invoke, Just not with ease,

Comment: Can't you mimick this behavior by setting the window position and size, based on the desktop size? Should be easy enough, just not very "clean"

Comment: Just pinvoke MoveWindow().

Comment: @HansPassant Did that already combining it with the answer of Nicolas. But I'm still kinda interested in using Aero.

Comment: There is no Aero specific function for this.  There just isn't any need when you can use MoveWindow.

Comment: Not to argue with @HansPassant or anything, but `MoveWindow` is not exactly functionally equivalent to aero snap. If you aero snap a window to the side of the screen, you can double-click its title bar to restore it. If you `MoveWindow` a window to the side of the screen, double-clicking its title bar will maximize it.

Comment: You could fake that as well by storing the locations before MoveWindow, then perform another MoveWindow when the window is double clicked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not exactly the same but fakes it well:

```
ShowWindow(handle, SW_MAXIMIZE);
// for a split second you might see a maximized window here
MoveWindow(handle, 0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width / 2, Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height, true);
```

Answer (score 7):

This can be done without p/invoke.

Try this:

```
Rectangle rect = Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea;
rect.Width = rect.Width / 2;
Bounds = rect;
```

This will put the current window on the left of the primary screen.

Then just add this to put it on the right of the screen.

```
Location = new Point(rect.Width, 0);
```

Comment: I didn't accept because the window state isn't maximized. I tried it without WinApi (setting FormWindowState etc.) but it doesn't work out for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Will require heavy lifting for real-time placements, especially for non-child processes. Example - www.ishadow.com/vdm. For manual "fixing" of maximized windows position MoveWindow(hWnd, startPos, 0, winWidth, winHeight, true) after ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_MAXIMIZE) usually (try Task Manager on Windows 10) works as pointed above.