# Prevent Form resize on SW_MAXIMIZE

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, wndproc

I want to simulate Aero Snap functionality by my own. And for stick `Form` to a screen's side I'm using solution from this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18313673/programmatically-maximize-window-on-half-of-screen/18397468#18397468).
The problem is that after I call:

```
ShowWindow(Handle, SW_MAXIMIZE);
```

`Form` immediately maximizes and after call `MoveWindow` changes it's size to needed size. And this jump of the `Form` is visible and annoying. To prevent it I tried to disable handling of messages `WM_GETMINMAXINFO, WM_SIZE, WM_MOVE, WM_NCCALCSIZE, WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGING, WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED` in `WndProc`. It helps but not completely. Is there any analog `SuspendLayout()/ResumeLayout()` for `Form` resizing?

Comment: Could you hide the form first, then resize and then show the form again?

Comment: @AlexSanséau Doesn't help. `WinApi.ShowWindow(Handle, WinApi.SW_MAXIMIZE);` makes `Form` visible.

Comment: Just read the comments on the question and you'll see that this is not actually the solution that the OP used.  He used MoveWindow() as I recommended.

Comment: @HansPassant I can't see this in comments. I see that last update in question is his own answer. Or maybe I'm looking wrong?

Comment: "Did that already combining it with the answer of Nicolas".  Use MoveWindow().

Comment: @HansPassant, yes, I saw this comment from 19th of August. But also there is his answer from 23th of August where ShowWindow() and MoveWindow() are used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling message handling in `WndProc` helped me to reduce flickering (all except `WM_NCPAINT`):

```
bool ignoreMessages = false;

public void DockWindow()
{
    ignoreMessages = true;
    ShowWindow(handle, SW_MAXIMIZE);
    ignoreMessages = false;
    MoveWindow(handle, 0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width / 2, Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height, true);
}

protected override void WndProc(ref Message message)
{
    if (ignoreMessages &&
        message.Msg != WM_NCPAINT)
        return;

    base.WndProc(ref message);
}
```